# VBA error 438: copy to different workbooks using deactivate

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple code in order to copy some data from one workbook to another, as below:

```
     Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.RangeSelection.Copy
     End Sub
```

But when I try to run it, a message error appears: "error 438 , object doesn't support this property or method"

When I changed for this, it worked properly. Someone could please explain me why?

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).RangeSelection.Copy
    End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because RangeSelection is a property from the Window object and not from the sheet object.
Sheet doesn't have a property that would work for copying a selected Range.
You could use

```
Selection.Copy
```

To copy the selected Range in the active Sheet.
Or just use what you already have.

Comment: I used ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Selection.Copy but received the same error message. So does it mean selection isn´t a property of ActiveSheet? I tried only Selection.copy but the code made a copy of the second workbook (and I wanted to make a copy of the first).

Comment: Yes as I said activesheet doesn't have such a Property you could select the range beforehand with ThisWorkbook.Activesheet.UsedRange.Select

Comment: Or you could use ws1.Range(ws1.UsedRange.Address).Copy where ws1 is your first Worksheet

Comment: Nice if you wouldnt mind it would help alot if you accept the answer